# Keep using ixgbe module after upgrading to ubuntu 20

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, 20.04, kernel

I have an adopted old ubuntu 16.04 machine that I want to bring to ubuntu 20.04

The machine has a pcie card with sfp connectors. For this, the ixgbe module is installed.

Details:

```
$ modinfo ixgbe
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-137-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ixgbe/ixgbe.ko
version:        4.2.1-k
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) 10 Gigabit PCI Express Network Driver
author:         Intel Corporation, <linux.nics@intel.com>
srcversion:     D4157436D98B0B8AD792E3C
depends:        mdio,ptp,dca,vxlan
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-137-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 
parm:           max_vfs:Maximum number of virtual functions to allocate per physical function - default is zero and maximum value is 63. (Deprecated) (uint)
parm:           allow_unsupported_sfp:Allow unsupported and untested SFP+ modules on 82599-based adapters (uint)
parm:           debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all) (int)
```

And config:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/ixgbe.conf 
options ixgbe allow_unsupported_sfp=1
```

My main worry is: will this keep working after doing the upgrade procedure? Does a new version of the kernel module get installed or does nothing need to happen? Or will those network connectors stop working and will I need to do a manual install?

Answer (score 1):

The module `ixgbe` is present in all recent Ubuntu versions up to the current 5.15.0-xx. Your ethernet device should be covered perfectly.

In the event that the ixgbe.conf file doesn't carry forward in the upgrade, I suggest that you make a note of it and be prepared to write it again. The *allow_unsupported_sfp* parameter is the same.